# C# ScriptTask not working when run through Dtexec or SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

[Identical question with no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449209/ssis-package-is-working-fine-in-ssdt-but-throwing-an-error-in-a-sql-server-agent).

I have an issue with my SSIS projects where I cannot create a project that has a
`Microsoft.ScriptTask` in it without encountering some bizarre error messages. The underlying issue is that the content of the `Microsoft.ScriptTask` doesn't matter. The task can be empty and it will result in an identical error.

All scripts ran within Visual Studio work fine.

I have looked at multiple solutions including:

1. [Checking in your program files to see if the right version of `DTExec` is being used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886706/ssis-script-task-not-working-when-called-through-dtexec) As shown in the excerpt, I am indeed using the 150 version aka SQL Server 2019.
2. [Most solutions on this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/555c8b6b-c602-40d3-8a72-e3b9cf493b8e/dtexec-run-with-error-cannot-load-script-for-execution?forum=sqlintegrationservices) which include checking that [the package version is the same as the currently downloaded version of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033461/ssis-script-task-version-15-0-script-that-is-not-supported-when-deployed-in-act) (they are both 2019 version 15) and checking the encryption type of the solution to see if the sensitive data could be at fault.
3. [Reinstalling SSDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893267/ssis-script-task-vs15-not-work-when-deploy-on-sql-server-2014).
4. [Running everything as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146934/sql-server-job-with-file-system-ssis-package) from the CMD that runs DTExec to Visual Studio 2019 which runs the code.
5. [Rebuilding the script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/119278/why-does-a-script-task-not-execute-unless-the-whol.html).
6. As recommended by my senior, checking to see if DTExec was running on 32-bit or 64-bit. (If `DTExec` launches from `Program Files(x86)`, it is most likely 32-bit. If it launches from `Program Files`, it is most likely 64-bit). It is indeed running on 64-bit.
7. Another recommendation was to attempt to run the package through SSMS's Agent Profiler which resulted in the same error.
8. Checking to see if the .Net Framework version on my computer ([through checking the GAC](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-quickly-check-net-framework-version-windows-10)) is the same as the target version of the package. They are both 4.8.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\Dtexec.exe" /f "C:\Directory\Documents\SSIS Tests\TEST_PROJECT\Package.dtsx"
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 15.0.2000.5 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  16:35:16
Error: 2022-10-20 16:35:17.17
   Code: 0xC001F02A
   Source: Sequence Container
   Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Script Task", type "Microsoft.ScriptTask" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".
End Error
Error: 2022-10-20 16:35:17.17
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: Script Task
   Description: Failed to load task "Script Task", type "". The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2022-10-20 16:35:17.18
   Code: 0xC0010026
   Source: Script Task
   Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2022-10-20 16:35:17.18
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Script Task
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Error: 2022-10-20 16:35:17.18
   Code: 0xC0010025
   Source: Package
   Description: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.
End Error
```

I hope this is enough information and that someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have other SQL Server 2019 instances on which you could test the package? i.e.: Does the package execute successfully on a different server, suggesting configuration issues on the current one? Does the problem server actually have the Integration Services components installed? Is the problem server [up to date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146437/c-sharp-scripttask-not-working-when-run-through-dtexec-or-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment130911986_74146437)'s comment, the issue was with my SQL Server installation.
I hadn't [downloaded SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16) when I originally installed my SQL Server instance which meant that none of my SSIS packages were running properly.